# jsstore variable not found

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am using jsStore for indexedDB , I am getting this error .
Saying jsStore not found. How to include the jsStore variable ?.
Which file should I include and how ?

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFilJ.png)

edit****

[new error after adding the src ,says that failed to contruct worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJAKJ.png)

Comment: can elaborate your question.did you include jsstore script files in your home page?

Comment: yes i have included

Comment: i used this `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsstore/dist/jsstore.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsstore/dist/jsstore.worker.min.js"></script> `

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Show the code and error messages as text, not as images.

Comment: cdn scripts are not allowed to run under a worker. so just run it without worker. like this - var con =new JsStore.Instance();

Comment: the error basically says - its not able to find the file : jsstore.worker.min.js. Please have a look at web worker doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as @Ujjwal Gupta said. It needs to run under a worker , so my problem was solved by using the the non-worker JsStore syntax. That is without calling the worker

`var connection = new JsStore.Instance()`

Do not call the JsStore Instance with worker without using Server.